# call methods from Array instance of the interface

Tags: java

```
interface Sporty {

    public void beSporty();
}

class Ferrari implements Sporty {
    public void beSporty() {
        System.out.println("inside Ferrari impelemnting Sporty");
    }
}
class RacingFlats implements Sporty {
    public void beSporty() {
        System.out.println("inside RacingFlats impelemnting Sporty");
    }
}

public class TestSportythings {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sporty[] sportyThings = new Sporty[3];
        sportyThings[0] = new Ferrari();
        sportyThings[1] = new RacingFlats();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Yes. You can call `sportyThings[i].beSporty();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can ***call methods from Array instance of the interface*** by an object of a class which is implemented that method of the interface.

Like the following:

```
sportyThings[0].beSporty();
```

And you will get output:

> inside Ferrari impelemnting Sporty

But if you call `beSporty()` by

```
sportyThings[2].beSporty();
```

You will get `NullPointerException` as `sportyThings[2]` is not initialized (by `new`).